# model fit: use intermediate layer from another model as Input with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I looked up the threads but seems no one addressed the same issue I'm having.

[image]

I am trying to reconstruct a model of Bi-CNN, and I am creating 3 separate models for debugging purposes. What I did for the `model_cross` highlighted in the picture was:

```
cross = something like tf.transpose(tf.matmul(left_intermediate, right_intermediate))`
cross_input = Input(shape=cross[1:])
cross_output = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(cross_input)
cross_model = Model(inputs=cross_input, outputs=cross_output)
cross_model.summary()
```

Then I concatenated the output of left, cross and right models:

```
combined = Concatenate(aixs=1)([left_output, cross_ouput, right_output])
combined_output = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[left_input, right_input, cross_input], outputs=combined_output)
```

It was all fine here, but when I did:

```
model.compile(...)
model.fit(x=[left, right, cross], y=labels)
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

and the output of `cross` was:

```
Tensor("Transpose_2:0", shape=(None, 6, 5, 20), dtype=float32)
```

I am wondering what was wrong and what's the quick fix?
I can work things around by this:

```
cross = something like tf.transpose(tf.matmul(left_intermediate, right_intermediate))`
# cross_input = Input(shape=cross[1:])
cross_output = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(cross)
```

But I'd like to have the `cross_model` output its summary, thus I think I need to have an `Input`.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems u don't need to put cross in model inputs and also the definition of cross_input seems useless

Comment: I thought I needed it for the model summary after `cross_model = Model(inputs=cross_input, outputs=cross_output)`

Comment: I don't specify the cross_input and when the whole model is built I make extraction of the layers I need to build cross_model... this is an option... is it also possible to show how u build all the model in keras so I can try how I said u